# Further train Samsung Galaxy S6 fingerprint reader

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I know that with iOS there's a trick that allows you to keep on entering your fingerprint for training after the basic mandatory set.

Is there such a thing for Android with a Samsung Galaxy S6?